# Need a help in Query to check whether Task is completed by other user or not before showing on dashboard

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in database Task, User & assignedTo.

Task contains information of Task created by Admin, User is list of User & assignedTo contains information about which task assign to which user.

i need to query on 'assignedTo' table to show a list of Task assigned to users on their Dashboard. Problem is a single Task is assigned to multiple user and it may possible task may be completed by one of them. So i need to show task which are in Open Status and not completed by anyone in assigned list.
Below is structure of 'assignedTo' Table:

```
--------------------------------
| id | taskId | userId | status|
--------------------------------
| 1  |  1     | 1      | open  |  
| 2  |  1     | 2      | open  |
| 3  |  1     | 3      | open  |
| 4  |  1     | 4      | open  |
| 5  |  2     | 1      | open  |
| 6  |  2     | 2      | close |
| 7  |  3     | 1      | open  |
| 8  |  3     | 2      | open  |
--------------------------------
```

So as per above data, Task 1 is shown on user 1,2,3 & 4 Dashboard as it is not closed by any of them.
Task 2 is shown on no one's Dash as it is closed by User 2.
Similarly, Task 3 is shown on user 1 & 2 Dash as it is open for both of them.

i tried to join same table to it's own but failed to execute.

```
SELECT * FROM assignedTo  a1
JOIN assignedTo a2 ON a2.taskId = a1.taskId AND a2.userId != 1 AND a2.status = 'open' 
WHERE a1.userId = 1 AND a1.status = 'open'
```

Please help with Query if possible.

Comment: One small issue is, no need the double equal symbol here `a2.status == 'open'`

Comment: @Arulkumar Question Updated, typing mistake...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  A1.*, 
        CASE WHEN A2.taskId IS NULL THEN 'Task Completed' 
        ELSE 'open' END AS CurrentStatus
FROM AssignedTo A1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT taskId
    FROM AssignedTo 
    WHERE status IN ('open', 'close')
    GROUP BY taskId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 1
    ) A2 ON A2.taskId = A1.taskId
ORDER BY A1.taskId;
```

Fiddler: http://rextester.com/CAHOPS39734

Help from this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97935/68079)

---

The above query will return one extra column as `CurrentStatus`. If the taskId has any `close` status, for those tasks the `CurrentStatus` will be `Task Completed` and for remaining tasks it will show as `open` only.

So the output will be:

```
id  taskId  userId  status  CurrentStatus
1   1       1       open    open
4   1       4       open    open
2   1       2       open    open
3   1       3       open    open
5   2       1       open    Task Completed
6   2       2       close   Task Completed
7   3       1       open    open
8   3       2       open    open
```

Comment: Would not that also return tasks that are closed and assigned to one userId? You could change the having clause to `HAVING COUNT( case status when 'close' then 1 end ) = 0` to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation of @Ankumars answer. Since 'close' is less than 'open':

```
SELECT  A1.*, A2.status as current_status
FROM AssignedTo A1
JOIN (
    SELECT taskID, min(status) as status
    FROM AssignedTo
    GROUP BY taskId
) A2
    ON A1.taskId = A2.taskId;
```